# Sending data to a Fragment instead of an Activity with a Parcelable object

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, parcelable

I want to send data to a Fragment with a Parcelable class I've made.

I know this is how you'd go about things when using an Activity (ObjectA being the class that extends Parcelable):

```
ObjectA obj = new ObjectA();   
// Set values etc.   
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class); 
i.putExtra("com.package.ObjectA", obj);   
startActivity(i);
```

But as you can't use intents with Fragments, I've got no idea how to do this.

Can I even use a Parcelable class? If not, what should I use? I it is possible, how?

Edit/update:

I've updated with your recommendations, but still don't get everything.

This is the fragment we use to create a list view:

```
package com.tsjd.HotMeals;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.tabtest.R;

public class RecipeListViewFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<String> titles;
    ArrayList<String> descriptions;
    ArrayList<String> images;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RecipeListViewParcer object = getArguments().getParcelable("extraObject");
        titles = object.getTitles();
        descriptions = object.getDescriptions();
        images = object.getImages();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipelistview, container,
                false);

        final ListView listview = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);


        RecipeListViewAdapter adapter = new RecipeListViewAdapter(
                getActivity(), titles);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // do something with the data
    }
}
```

I want to use this ListView for different things, so I want to be able to send the three ArrayLists to it. For this I've made a class that implements Parcelable, this is it:

```
package com.tsjd.HotMeals;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class RecipeListViewParcer implements Parcelable{

    private ArrayList<String> titles;
    private ArrayList<String> descriptions;
    private ArrayList<String> images;

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private RecipeListViewParcer(Parcel in) {
            titles = (ArrayList<String>) in.readSerializable();
            descriptions = (ArrayList<String>) in.readSerializable();
            images = (ArrayList<String>) in.readSerializable();
        }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTitles()
    {
        return titles;
    }

    public void setTitles(ArrayList<String> titles){
        this.titles = titles;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getDescriptions()
    {
        return descriptions;
    }

    public void setDescriptions(ArrayList<String> descriptions){
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getImages()
    {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(ArrayList<String> images){
        this.images = images;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeSerializable(titles);
        out.writeSerializable(descriptions);
        out.writeSerializable(images);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<RecipeListViewParcer> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<RecipeListViewParcer>() {
        public RecipeListViewParcer createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new RecipeListViewParcer(in);
        }

        public RecipeListViewParcer[] newArray(int size) {
            return new RecipeListViewParcer[size];
        }
    };



}
```

Finally, this is a Fragment which uses the listview to show favourite recipes, here I want to send three ArrayLists, this is the only code that currently has errors. I don't know how to declare the Parcel I need for the constructor of my Parcelable class, how should I go about this? (I haven't put anything in my ArrayLists yet, but I hope the idea is clear).

```
package com.tsjd.HotMeals;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MyRecipesFragment extends Fragment {


    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();



    Parcel in = new Parcel();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = new RecipeListViewFragment();

        RecipeListViewParcer obj = new RecipeListViewParcer(in);

        obj.setDescriptions(descriptions);
        obj.setTitles(titles);
        obj.setImages(images);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("extraObject", obj);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: use bundle and setit to the fragment

Comment: Try to debug, what are you receive in `RecipeListViewParcer(Parcel in)` constructor method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the FragmentManager:

Send the 3 ArrayLists in Activity:

> ```
>        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
>        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
>        Fragment fragment = new ViewControllerFragment();
>
>        ObjectA obj = new ObjectA();
>        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
>        bundle.putStringArrayList("Titles", obj.getTitles());
>        bundle.putStringArrayList("Descriptions", obj.getDescriptions());
>        bundle.putStringArrayList("Images", obj.getImages());
>        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
>
>        fragmentTransaction.commit();
> ```

Get Object in Fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();                    
 titles = bundle.getStringArrayList("Titles");            
descriptions= bundle.getStringArrayList("Descriptions");            
images= bundle.getStringArrayList("Images");
```

Or just try other Posts: [Send data from activity to fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Comment: Could you look at my update/edit? It gives a lot more information on the situation and I've got some minor problems that still have to be solved

Comment: Forget about the idea with Parcelables and try to get die 3 ArrayLists in the Activity and put them into the bundle: bundle.putStringArrayList("extraTitles", object.getTitles());     bundle.putStringArrayList("XXX", object.getXXX);